# XHR request $.Ajax taking to long to respond after while

Tags: php, ajax, jqxhr

I know it maybe reported as duplicated, but I lost a lot of time (3 weeks) digging online everywhere trying to find a solution..

I'm working on [php](/questions/tagged/php) application for a [sip](/questions/tagged/sip) - [asterisk](/questions/tagged/asterisk) which allow me to get agents working on it.. and when I run my Application, I had an issue that [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) Stalled for so long, then after a lot of search, I knew that I have to close sessions using `session_write_close();` after I put my data into it.

now I have a different situation, The same file takes about 2 sec. in the first I install my Application into my server "**localserver, CentOS**".
[image]

now and after 2 or 3 weeks, it takes 20 sec!!! and I don't know why?!!!
[image]

- here's my Ajax code:

.

```
$("#totagentdetails").click(function () {
        $("#modal-body").html("");
    var queue = $("#queue").val();

        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getdetails.php',
                data: {"queue":queue, "asker":"totagents"},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.res != "error"){
                            $("#modal-title").html("Total agents details:");
                            $("#modal-body").html(response.tbldetails);
                    }else{
                            var result = response.msg;
                            alert(result);
                    }
                 }
            });

});
```

and here's "getdetails.php" code:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_write_close();
include_once("../functions/main_config.php");
include_once("../functions/function_mrh.php");
include_once("../functions/enc_dec.php");
include('../phpseclib1.0.9/Net/SSH2.php');

$queue = $_POST['queue'];
$asker = $_POST['asker'];

date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Cairo");

switch ($asker) {
    case "totagents":
    case "readyagents":
    case "hascalls":
    case "waitingcalls":
    case "breaks":
        $command = '/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "queue show  '.$queue.'"';
        break;

    default:
        $command = "error!";
}

$connection = ssh2_connect($sip_host, 22); 
ssh2_auth_password($connection,$sip_user,$sip_pass); 
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection,$command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$output = stream_get_contents($stream);
$output = rtrim($output);
$output  = explode("\n", $output );


switch ($asker) {
    case "totagents":
        $finalRes = "
        <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Agent name</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Num. of calls</th>
                    <th>Total sign in</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

        ";


        foreach($output as $key=>$value) {
            if ($key > 1){
                if (trim($value) == "No Callers"){
                    break;
                } elseif (trim($value) == "Callers:"){
                    break;
                }else{

                    @list($agentName, $restOfTheLine) = explode("(SIP/", $value);
                    $finalRes .= "<tr><td>".trim($agentName) ."</td>"; 

                    @list($Ext, $restOfTheLine) = explode("from", $restOfTheLine);
                    $finalRes .= "<td>".trim($Ext) ."</td>"; 

                    @list($stat, $restOfTheLine) = explode(") has", $restOfTheLine);
                        // get break type if it == "paused) (N"
                        if (strpos(mb_substr($stat, 42, 10), 'paused') !== false) {
                                $dbh6 = @mysql_connect($app_host, $app_user, $app_pass) or die ("error in host-log connection");
                                        @mysql_select_db($log_database, $dbh6) or die("error in agentsaction database selections"); 

                            $qry = "select status from ".$log_database.".livecounter where ext='".trim($Ext)."';";
                            $result = mysql_query($qry);
                            if($result){
                                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                                $stat = $row['status'];
                                include_once("../functions/closelogdb_mrh.php");
                            } else {
                                $stat = "paused";
                            }
                        } else {
                            $stat = mb_substr($stat, 42, 10);
                            if(trim($stat) == "Unavailabl"){$stat = "Unavailable";}
                            if(trim($stat) == "Not in use"){$stat = "Ready";}
                        }


                    $finalRes .= "<td>".trim($stat)."</td>";            

                    @list($hasTake, $restOfTheLine) = explode("taken", $restOfTheLine);
                    $hasTake = mb_substr($restOfTheLine, 0, 3);
                        if (trim($hasTake) == "no"){$hasTake = 0;}

                    $finalRes .= "<td>".trim($hasTake)."</td>"; 


                    //calc inqueuetot from database

                                $dbh6 = @mysql_connect($app_host, $app_user, $app_pass) or die ("error in host-log connection");
                                        @mysql_select_db($log_database, $dbh6) or die("error in agentsaction database selections"); 

                            $qry = "select * from ".$log_database.".livecounter where ext='".trim($Ext)."';";
                            $result = mysql_query($qry);
                            if($result){
                                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                                $logdatetime = $row['logdatetime'];
                                $current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $alllogTime = subTwoDates_2from1($current_datetime, $logdatetime);
                            } else {
                                $alllogTime = "N/A";
                            }

                            $finalRes .= "<td>".$alllogTime."</td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }


        $finalRes .= "
            </tbody>
        </table>
        ";
        break;

    default:
        $command = "error!";
}



       echo json_encode(array("res" => "greatJob", "msg" => $output, "tbldetails" => $finalRes)); 


?>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

interesting comment from @RamRaider, but I didn't understand a lot of things, I typed **torch://net-internals/#events** in address-bar then I clicked on **URL_REQUEST**  for the "getdetails.php" file, and it loads a bunch of data:

```
194691: URL_REQUEST
https://10.1.80.7/cc/supervisor/getdetails.php
Start Time: 2018-03-04 13:06:35.765

t=559792 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=20486]
                     --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                     --> url = "https://10.1.80.7/cc/supervisor/getdetails.php"
t=559793 [st=    1]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=6]
t=559793 [st=    1]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=4]
                         --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension IDM Integration Module"
t=559798 [st=    6]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=1]
                         --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension AdGuard AdBlocker"
t=559799 [st=    7]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=559799 [st=    7]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=20466]
                       --> load_flags = 33024 (MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                       --> method = "POST"
                       --> upload_id = "0"
                       --> url = "https://10.1.80.7/cc/supervisor/getdetails.php"
t=559799 [st=    7]     +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=4]
t=559799 [st=    7]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=2]
                           --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension IDM Integration Module"
t=559801 [st=    9]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=2]
                           --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension IDM Integration Module"
t=559803 [st=   11]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=559803 [st=   11]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=559803 [st=   11]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=96]
t=559803 [st=   11]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 194693 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=559899 [st=  107]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 194693 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=559899 [st=  107]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=559900 [st=  108]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=559900 [st=  108]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=68]
t=559900 [st=  108]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 194697 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=559968 [st=  176]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 194697 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=559968 [st=  176]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=559968 [st=  176]     +UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
t=559968 [st=  176]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
                           --> is_chunked = false
                           --> net_error = 0 (?)
                           --> total_size = 23
t=559968 [st=  176]     -UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT
                         --> is_chunked = false
                         --> net_error = 0 (?)
                         --> total_size = 23
t=559968 [st=  176]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=559968 [st=  176]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                           --> POST /cc/supervisor/getdetails.php HTTP/1.1
                               Host: 10.1.80.7
                               Connection: keep-alive
                               Content-Length: 23
                               Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
                               Origin: https://10.1.80.7
                               X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
                               User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.0.12335 Safari/537.36
                               Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
                               DNT: 1
                               Referer: https://10.1.80.7/cc/supervisor/index.php
                               Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                               Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6
                               Cookie: [36 bytes were stripped]
t=559968 [st=  176]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
                           --> did_merge = false
                           --> is_chunked = false
                           --> length = 23
t=559968 [st=  176]       +UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                           --> current_position = 0
t=559968 [st=  176]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                             --> current_position = 0
t=559968 [st=  176]       -UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ
t=559969 [st=  177]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                           --> current_position = 23
t=559969 [st=  177]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=559969 [st=  177]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=20288]
t=559969 [st=  177]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=20288]
t=580257 [st=20465]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                           --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                               Date: Sun, 04 Mar 2018 11:06:29 GMT
                               Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16
                               X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
                               Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
                               Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
                               Pragma: no-cache
                               Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
                               Connection: Keep-Alive
                               Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                               Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
t=580257 [st=20465]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=580257 [st=20465]     +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=8]
t=580257 [st=20465]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=5]
                           --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension IDM Integration Module"
t=580262 [st=20470]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=3]
                           --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension AdGuard AdBlocker"
t=580265 [st=20473]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=580265 [st=20473]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
t=580265 [st=20473]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
t=580266 [st=20474]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=11]
t=580277 [st=20485]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                       --> byte_count = 9775
t=580278 [st=20486]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=580278 [st=20486]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                       --> byte_count = 1
t=580278 [st=20486]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=580278 [st=20486] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Comment: These might be of interest? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740692/request-stalled-for-a-long-time-occasionally-in-chrome, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010156/stalled-and-pending-ajax-requests-by-jquery-in-chrome/30068579

Comment: interesting, but if you please see **update1**

Comment: It seemed that the bottleneck is between these two lines, which takes
near 20 seconds (the dt=20288):   in **t=559969 [st=  177]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=20288]
t=559969 [st=  177]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=20288]
t=580257 [st=20465]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS**

Comment: I won't pretend to understand how to diagnose these logs but I see your point regarding the apparent bottleneck. Does this occur in other browsers or just Chrome?

Comment: unfortunately yes